# Update/append redis values

Tags: php, redis

I have recently started using redis. Currently it's simple key value storage. For example:

```
$this->redis->set('GET_ALL_DEVICES', json_encode($data));
```

Now if there is new entry into device table, I want to append new entry into same cached data I have. Don't want to flush cached object and create new one to reflect new entry. Is there any way to do this in redis?

Answer (score 1):

There is no table in Redis. You must learn what [Redis specific data types](http://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro) are.

In this case, a SET could be the right structure to be used, if you don't need the data to be ordered. So you should perform a [SADD](http://redis.io/commands/sadd) (adds a value to  SET) instead of a [SET](http://redis.io/commands/set) instruction, which sets the value for a single string.

```
$this->redis->sadd('GET_ALL_DEVICES', json_encode($data));
```

According to your use case, a LIST or a SORTED set may be more appropriate than a SET to store your data.